# toggle() is not working and append more field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

div show after input click event.i'm added toggle function when i'll click input field div will show but i stuck in when i click more time input field div will not toggle and more div will append

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#date_id").on("click", function(){
       this.insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", "<div id='lbl_date'>test</div>");
     });
      $("#lbl_date").toggle();
    });
```

```css
  #lbl_date{
    position: relative;
    background-color:#FFAA41;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text"  id="date_id" class="date"/>
    <label for="lbl_date">date</label>
```

after i'm using `$('').off()` and `$().one()` this but again toggle div not working it's possible please help me
**Expect** when i'll click input field div will toggle

Comment: ID should be unique. Use event delegation.

Comment: toggle typo in your code

Comment: its `.toggle()` not `.toogle()`

Comment: sry guradio now i'm change it's not working

Comment: What is the purpose of hiding same input on click?

Comment: @vijay just like what the first comment said ***NO TO DUPLICATE ID*** use class instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do like following trick what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#date_id").one("click", function(){
       this.insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", "<div id='div_date'>test</div>");
     });
  $("#date_id").on("click", function(){
      $("#div_date").toggle();
    });
    });
```

```css
#div_date{
    position: relative;
    background-color:#FFAA41;
  display:none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text"  id="date_id" class="date"/>
    <label for="lbl_date">date</label>
```

**Note:** `id` must be unique.